# How to add keyboard shortcut with MOD3 modifier in KDE?

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde, plasma-5

I like setting right control as different modifier, mod3, by patching the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` like that:

```
--- orig.txt    2018-06-10 15:36:53.479009368 +0200
+++ mod.txt 2018-06-10 15:42:08.995666676 +0200
@@ -34,8 +34,9 @@
     // Beginning of modifier mappings.
     modifier_map Shift  { Shift_L, Shift_R };
     modifier_map Lock   { Caps_Lock };
-    modifier_map Control{ Control_L, Control_R };
+    modifier_map Control{ Control_L };
     modifier_map Mod2   { Num_Lock };
+    modifier_map Mod3   { Control_R };
     modifier_map Mod4   { Super_L, Super_R };

     // Fake keys for virtual<->real modifiers mapping:
```

After that I can use right control together with arrows to manage virtual desktops (e.g. `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['<Mod3>Down']"`)

This method works on Ubuntu 18.04 under Gnome 3, but KDE 5 Plasma seems to ignore the Mod3 modifier altogether. Did anyone managed to bind any keyboard modifier other than Shift, Ctrl or Alt in KDE? If so, how?